# Знаки препинания: Касса является кооперативом, по отношению к которому, по вопросам, неурегулированным законом,

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я поставила знаки препинания в данном предложении:

"Касса является кооперативом, по отношению к которому, по вопросам, неурегулированным законом, применяются законоположения от 16 сентября 1982 г. - Кооперативное право".

Нужна ли запятая после слова "которому", если нет - почему?

Answer (score 3):

*Касса является кооперативом, по отношению к которому по вопросам, НЕ урегулированным законом, применяются законоположения от 16 сентября 1982 г...*

Запятая не нужна, правильно раздельное написание. Ну и фраза, конечно, ух... Тяжеловатая.

"Если нет - почему" - странный вопрос. Вот "если да - почему" - это правомерный вопрос. А на нет и суда нет. Нет причин для постановки запятой, вот она и не ставится.

Comment: Прекрасно всё растолковали, браво! Особенно имею в виду последний абзац.

Answer (score 3):

Отвечу проще и цитататой:

**По отноше́нию (к)**

> Устойчивое сочетание (фразема). Используется в качестве составного
>   предлога (с последующим к + дат. п.).

Мы имеем дело с составным предлогом, а предлог не отделяется от слова, которому служит.

А само предложение не просто тяжеловато, оно не имеет право на жизнь.

Может (только предположение!) так:

**Касса является кооперативом, по отношению к которому вопросы, не урегулированным законом, подчиняются законоположению от 16 сентября 1982 г. (Кооперативное право).**

Не разобравшись, кто на ком стоял, пошла проверять закон и... в России (в СССР) не было такого. А принятый в Польше иначе называется.

> Вопросы, касающиеся членов жилищных кооперативов, регулируются Законом
>   от 16 сентября 1982 года о кооперативах и подзаконными актами
>   кооперативов.

[См. Гришина Я.С.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2) (г. Саратов). Сравнительно-правовое исследование социального предпринимательства в странах Америки и Европы.// Вестник Пермского университета: Юридические науки. — Пермский государственный национальный исследовательский университет, 2012. — Вып. 2 (16).